# Can the closed unit ball in a compact subset of an infinite-dimensional Banach space be compact?

Tags: solution-verification, compactness

I know Riesz's Lemma tells us that given a normed vector space $(X,||\cdot||)$, the closed unit ball $\{x \in X: ||x||\leqslant 1\}$ is compact iff $X$ is finite-dimensional.

I am considering a (infinite-dimensional) Banach space $(X,||\cdot||)$ and a compact subset $S \subset X$. Is it true that $B := \{x \in S: ||x|| \leqslant 1\}$ is compact? As $B \subset S$, $B$ is compact if it is closed. And $B$ is closed by definition: given $\{x_{n}\} \in B$ with $||x_{n}-x|| \to 0$ and $x \in S$, we have
$$
||x|| = ||x-x_{n}+x_{n}|| \leqslant ||x-x_{n}|| + ||x_{n}|| = ||x-x_{n}|| + 1,
$$

which implies that $||x|| \leqslant 1$ and hence, $x \in B$.

Can this result be correct? I've checked it over and couldn't find a mistake nor similar questions (but perhaps it's so trivial no one felt the need to ask, yet here I am...)

Comment: Closed subsets of compact are compact, but $S$ is not a linear subspace.

Comment: @user10354138: I think the OP already knows that closed subsets of compact sets are compact (see the second sentence of their second paragraph). They just want some reassurance that their reasoning is sound. Everything looks fine to me.

Comment: @user10354138 maybe i'm not understanding your comment. Indeed $S$ is not a linear subspace, but does this affect the conclusion? I wasn't aware $S$ needs to be a subspace for $B$ to be compact

Comment: No, I'm just saying $S$ isn't a linear subspace so there is no contradiction from Riesz, if that is what was troubling you.